# Azure Media Services - v3 Overlay position issue

Tags: azure-media-services

I am working on an encoding flow that adds an overlay image to the video. I want this watermark to be in the bottom right corner. No matter what I try with the position parameter, the watermark is positioned in the top left.

Can someone point me to a sample that covers that scenario? The Microsoft docs and samples are vague about positioning the overlay and setting the opacity.

Here is a snippet of code that contains my transform definition. Regardless of the overlay settings, I can use any values for the rectangle position element and nothing changes. The watermark ends up in the upper right of the video. Its like the position and opacity properties are being ignored.

```
 new AMSModels.TransformOutput(
            new AMSModels.StandardEncoderPreset(
                 filters: new AMSModels.Filters
                        {
                            Overlays = new List<AMSModels.Overlay>
                            {
                                new AMSModels.VideoOverlay()
                                {
                                    InputLabel =  "tbvvideooverlay",
                                    Opacity = .5,
                                    Position = new AMSModels.Rectangle(){ Left = "100", Top = "100", Width = "100", Height = "100"} //**I've tried all types of values here including percentages, nothing changes when I reencode the video.**


                                }
                            }
                        },
                codecs: new AMSModels.Codec[]
                {
                    // Add an AAC Audio layer for the audio encoding
                    new AMSModels.AacAudio(
                        channels: 2,
                        samplingRate: 48000,
                        bitrate: 128000,
                        profile: AMSModels.AacAudioProfile.AacLc
                    ),
                    // Next, add a H264Video for the video encoding
                   new AMSModels.H264Video (
                        // Set the GOP interval to 2 seconds for all H264Layers
                        keyFrameInterval:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                         // Add H264Layers. Assign a label that you can use for the output filename
                        layers:  new AMSModels.H264Layer[]
                        {
                            new AMSModels.H264Layer (
                                bitrate: 3600000, // Units are in bits per second and not kbps or Mbps - 3.6 Mbps or 3,600 kbps
                                width: "1280",
                                height: "720",
                                label: "3600" // This label is used to modify the file name in the output formats
                            ),
                            new AMSModels.H264Layer (
                                bitrate: 1600000, // Units are in bits per second and not kbps or Mbps - 1.6 Mbps or 1600 kbps
                                width: "960",
                                height: "540",
                                label: "1600" // This label is used to modify the file name in the output formats
                            ),
                            new AMSModels.H264Layer (
                                bitrate: 600000, // Units are in bits per second and not kbps or Mbps - 0.6 Mbps or 600 kbps
                                width: "640",
                                height: "360",
                                label: "600" // This label is used to modify the file name in the output formats
                            ),
                        }
                    ),
                    // Also generate a set of PNG thumbnails
                    new AMSModels.PngImage(
                        start: "10%",
                        step: "10%",
                        range: "90%",
                        layers: new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models.PngLayer[]{
                            new AMSModels.PngLayer(
                                width: "100%",
                                height: "100%"
                            )
                        }
                    ),
                    new AMSModels.JpgImage(
                        start: "10%",
                        step: "10%",
                        range: "90%",
                        layers: new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models.JpgLayer[]{
                            new AMSModels.JpgLayer(
                                quality: 100,
                                width: "100%",
                                height: "100%"
                            )
                        }
                    )
                },
                // Specify the format for the output files - one for video+audio, and another for the thumbnails
                formats: new AMSModels.Format[]
                {
                    // Mux the H.264 video and AAC audio into MP4 files, using basename, label, bitrate and extension macros
                    // Note that since you have multiple H264Layers defined above, you have to use a macro that produces unique names per H264Layer
                    // Either {Label} or {Bitrate} should suffice
                     
                    new AMSModels.Mp4Format(
                        filenamePattern:"{Basename}_{Resolution}_{Bitrate}{Extension}"
                    ),
                    new AMSModels.PngFormat(
                        filenamePattern:"Thumbnail-{Basename}-{Index}{Extension}"
                    ),

                      new AMSModels.JpgFormat(
                        filenamePattern:"Thumbnail-{Basename}-{Index}{Extension}"
                    )
                }
            ),
            onError: AMSModels.OnErrorType.StopProcessingJob,
            relativePriority: AMSModels.Priority.Normal
        )
        };

            string description = "A simple custom encoding transform with 2 MP4 bitrates";
            // Create the custom Transform with the outputs defined above
            transform = await client.Transforms.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, transformName, outputs, description);
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for identifying this concern and pointing it out.  We took a look at this and have confirmed that there is indeed a bug that you have found here! First off, thank you for finding this issue and reporting it.

Now the bad news, right now we are going to have to look at fixing that and redeploying a fix to production.  That could take some time on our side, so if you are in need of a quick solution the only thing I can suggest is to use the older v2 API (yes, the one we announced deprecation on) to work around this issue until we can get a code fix out to production.

Here is the older method of doing this in v2 if that works for you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#overlay

Comment: Quick update - we have a fix in for absolute pixel positioning in the V3 API for overlays, it will be in our April payload, which wont reach production until end of April. I'll try to get back to you here when it goes live.

Comment: Update - the fix is in production for absolute pixel positions

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question...where is the best documentation for this feature. It does seem to be positioning now, I just can't seem to get it in the bottom right. I will have videos that come in at different resolutions. I tried setting the left and top properties of the rectangle to 90% each, but it still shows in the upper left...but not totally justified in the top left. So I can tell the position attribute is doing something. If you had an example on how I could position a logo that is 75px by 75px in the bottom right, that would be very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: As noted above, the fix was only for "Absolute Pixel positioning" - and not for relative.  So using % based positioning wont work yet.

You have to know where exactly to place it in pixels to get it to land in the right location in the bottom right at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for confirming this. I've already migrated and committed to v3 so turning back would be messy.

I am still working on it, but I do have a workaround that will get me by. If I make and image the same size as my largest video size, I can then position the watermark in the bottom right in that image. As long as its a transparent PNG, it "looks" like the watermark is bottom right justified.

I have to put this solution to the test across all the video assets I have, but so far I think it will work until the patch above will work. Once that is fixed, I plan on allowing our users to pick from a variety of watermarks.

Thanks again!

Eric

Comment: Shared below, but doing it again here.  The fix for absolute pixel positioning is checked in, but it wont reach production until end of April. I'll update here when it does.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I am looking forward to it. My workaround is a bit wonky. When I have different sized input videos, the overlay position varies. I assume its set relative to the video size. I'll sit tight until the patch hits production.

Comment: So...Its the end of April :)  How are we looking on this fix?  Thank you!!

Comment: Fix should now be deployed in all regions as of this week.  
The fix supports overlay position in absolute pixels for now. We are still planning to add support for percentage based positioning in a follow-up fix.